# Django form validation not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
class SearchFilterForm(Form):
    fromdate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
todate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
```

Javascript:

```
function comparedate(){
        var fromdate = document.getElementById("id_fromdate").value;
        var todate = document.getElementById("id_todate").value;
        if(fromdate<todate){
            alert("Start date should be less than end date");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using this validation in search functionality for dates.

I used the above code for validating the from date and to date.My problem is,it is displaying the error message if the from date is less than to date.But after showing the message it go for searching and showing no records.

I should not go for search if the from date is less than to date and it should show the error message constant but this is showing the error message and goes for search.

Comment: Note I've removed all the Django tags from this question, as it appears to be purely a Javascript one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman,whole problem is not resolved,can you tell what might be the problem for this.

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing the HTML input elements themselves, not their contents. You probably want:

```
if(fromdate.value < todate.value)
```

Comment: @Damiel,validation is happening,but after showing the error message the searching function is happening and it is showing no records,but expected is should show error message and stop their if user change the date and press go it should check validation and search and display the result.